# Database Error: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, sql, install

I'm currently trying to install a Magento Extension (EM_ProductLabels) on my local xampp testing enviroment. I made a fresh installation and dropped the needed files in th correspondending folder. But when I open any side I get an 404 error. Here the error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:605:"Error in file: "C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\local\EM\Productlabels\sql\productlabels_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-name' for key 'UNQ_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_CODE', query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:980:"#0 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0')
#2 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.0.0')
#3 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

As far as I can tell the module tries to add an entry in the database at a place which is already occupied. So I took a look at the install script but it didn't helped me much:

```
<?php
$pathFile = Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'install_productlabels.txt';
if(file_exists($pathFile)){
    echo 'Installing Product Labels extension, please come back in some minutes ...';
    exit;
}
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/productlabels_entity_varchar')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/productlabels_entity_text')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/productlabels_entity_int')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/eav_attribute')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/productlabels')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/css_entity_text')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('productlabels/css')};
");

/* Create table 'productlabels/productlabels' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('productlabels/productlabels'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Entity ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Created Date')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        ), 'Updated Date')      
    ->setComment('Productlabels Entity Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/* Create table 'productlabels/productlabels_entity_varchar' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar')))
    ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Value Id')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Attribute Id')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Id')
    ->addColumn('value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        ), 'Value')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName(
            array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), array('attribute_id')),
        array('attribute_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), array('store_id')),
        array('store_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), array('entity_id')),
        array('entity_id'))
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), 'attribute_id', 'eav/attribute', 'attribute_id'),
        'attribute_id', $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), 'entity_id', 'productlabels/productlabels', 'entity_id'),
        'entity_id', $installer->getTable('productlabels/productlabels'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'varchar'), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id', $installer->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Label Entity Varchar');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/* Create table 'productlabels/productlabels_entity_int' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int')))
    ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Value Id')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Attribute Id')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Id')
    ->addColumn('value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        ), 'Value')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName(
            array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), array('attribute_id')),
        array('attribute_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), array('store_id')),
        array('store_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), array('entity_id')),
        array('entity_id'))
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), 'attribute_id', 'eav/attribute', 'attribute_id'),
        'attribute_id', $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), 'entity_id', 'productlabels/productlabels', 'entity_id'),
        'entity_id', $installer->getTable('productlabels/productlabels'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'int'), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id', $installer->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Label Entity Int');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/* Create table 'productlabels/productlabels_entity_text' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text')))
    ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Value Id')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Attribute Id')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Id')
    ->addColumn('value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
        ), 'Value')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName(
            array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), array('attribute_id')),
        array('attribute_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), array('store_id')),
        array('store_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), array('entity_id')),
        array('entity_id'))
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), 'attribute_id', 'eav/attribute', 'attribute_id'),
        'attribute_id', $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), 'entity_id', 'productlabels/productlabels', 'entity_id'),
        'entity_id', $installer->getTable('productlabels/productlabels'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/productlabels', 'text'), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id', $installer->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Label Entity Text');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/**
 * Create table 'productlabels/eav_attribute'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('productlabels/eav_attribute'))
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Attribute ID')
    ->addColumn('is_global', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '1',
        ), 'Is Global')
    ->addColumn('is_visible', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '1',
        ), 'Is Visible')
    ->addColumn('is_searchable', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Searchable')
    ->addColumn('is_filterable', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Filterable')
    ->addColumn('is_comparable', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Comparable')
    ->addColumn('is_visible_on_front', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Visible On Front')
    ->addColumn('is_html_allowed_on_front', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is HTML Allowed On Front')
    ->addColumn('is_used_for_price_rules', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Used For Price Rules')
    ->addColumn('is_filterable_in_search', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Filterable In Search')
    ->addColumn('used_in_product_listing', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Used In Product Listing')
    ->addColumn('used_for_sort_by', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Used For Sorting')
    ->addColumn('is_configurable', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '1',
        ), 'Is Configurable')
    ->addColumn('apply_to', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        ), 'Apply To')
    ->addColumn('is_visible_in_advanced_search', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Visible In Advanced Search')
    ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Position')
    ->addColumn('is_wysiwyg_enabled', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is WYSIWYG Enabled')
    ->addColumn('is_used_for_promo_rules', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Is Used For Promo Rules')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('productlabels/eav_attribute', array('used_for_sort_by')),
        array('used_for_sort_by'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('productlabels/eav_attribute', array('used_in_product_listing')),
        array('used_in_product_listing'))
    ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('productlabels/eav_attribute', 'attribute_id', 'eav/attribute', 'attribute_id'),
        'attribute_id', $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Productlabels EAV Attribute Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/* Create table 'productlabels/css' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('productlabels/css'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Entity ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'default'   => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')    
    ->setComment('Productlabels Css Entity Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

/* Create table 'productlabels/css_entity_text' */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable(array('productlabels/css', 'text')))
    ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true,
        ), 'Value Id')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Type Id')
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Attribute Id')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Store ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        ), 'Entity Id')
    ->addColumn('value', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
        ), 'Value')
    ->addIndex(
        $installer->getIdxName(
            array('productlabels/css', 'text'),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), array('attribute_id')),
        array('attribute_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), array('store_id')),
        array('store_id'))
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), array('entity_id')),
        array('entity_id'))
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), 'attribute_id', 'eav/attribute', 'attribute_id'),
        'attribute_id', $installer->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), 'entity_id', 'productlabels/css', 'entity_id'),
        'entity_id', $installer->getTable('productlabels/css'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(array('productlabels/css', 'text'), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
        'store_id', $installer->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
    ->setComment('Label Entity Text');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->installEntities(); 
$installer->endSetup(); 
unlink($pathFile);
```

Any ideas what is actually causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps :

1. Check all the attributes created by the file mysql4-install-1.0.0.php are in the product attribute list or not. If not then create all those attributes manually in admin-end.
2. If all the attributes are present in the attribute list, then delete or rename this file.
3. Clear cache and test the extension if everything is working as expected.

I have also similar issue while installing the extension (some other extension) and faced the similar issue.
I have performed the above mentioned steps to fix the issue.

**PS :: Please keep DB backup before performing any changes.**